# How can I use ormlite with Stetho?

Tags: android, ormlite, stetho

I'm now use Stetho(http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) to debug my app.But my database framework is ormlite and I can't inspect database in Chrome.Does it exist a method to achieve it?

Edit1:

I can just see some other database

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)?

Using [Stetho Integrations](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/#integrations) & [Stetho features](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/#features) you can Achieve Database Inspection for **SQL lite**.I don't think **ormlite** provides the same till now.

Comment: I's using sqllite database.I just use com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android to manage my database

Comment: They you would be able to log its data on chrome.

Comment: I add a picture.I can see other database and I can't see my database.Do I need add some config?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835926/ormlite-and-images-saved-as-blob-on-android go through this you will be able to find why its behaving so

Comment: I can't understand it.